# Google Plus Share Button ExpandTo not working

Tags: google-plus-one

I am currently using this code.

```
<g:plus action="share" annotation="bubble" expandTo="top" href="#">
```

The expandTo is not working though. The info popup just show below the share button. I need it to display on top.

Thanks for any help :)

Edit: It appears it displays relative to where there share button is displayed on screen. If it is at the bottom of the screen then the bubble appears on top.

Is there a way to force the bubble to the top?

Comment: give it a class and do say in the css : top:0px; ? not sure if it works

Comment: That kind of things doesn't work. Since "<g:plus ...>" doesn't display in the source code. The google plus script replace it with a generic unnamed div.